# When should one use the two-point compactification of $\mathbb R$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

The real line $\mathbb R$ has a one-point compactification $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$, where this "$\infty$" is at both ends of the line, so that the compactification is topologically a circle.

It also has a two-point compactification $\mathbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$.

With rational functions $\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}$ doesn't depend on whether it's $+$ or $-$.  With vertical asymptotes, if one wishes to distinguish between two different ways of blowing up, one could say $f(x)\to\infty\!-$, i.e. $f(x)$ approaches $\infty$ from below, instead of $f(x)\to+\infty$, and similarly for the other direction.  That makes rational functions continuous everywhere, including the points where they have vertical asymptotes and the point $x=\infty$.

With trigonometric functions, one can take the domain to be $\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$ and the codomain to be $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ and treat vertical asymptotes as with rational functions.  That also makes trigonometric functions continuous even at points where they have vertical asymptotes, and the function $\theta\mapsto\tan(\theta/2)$ becomes a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$.

This seems like a more felicitous way of doing things than any that involves two infinities.

When, then, should one distinguish between $\pm\infty$?  Part of the answer seems to be with exponential functions:
$$
e^x\to\begin{cases} 0 & \text{as }x\to-\infty, \\ \infty & \text{as }x\to+\infty. \end{cases}
$$
In that case, it doesn't seem to make as much sense to say "as $x\to\infty\!+$" and "as $x\to\infty\!-$".  Similarly
$$
\arctan x \to \pm\frac\pi2\text{ according as }x\to\pm\infty.
$$

Is there more to the story than that?  If not, should we abandon $\pm$ in the case of rational functions and trigonometric functions?

Comment: I have a vague, half-remembered idea that the rational functions are exactly the holomorphic maps from the Riemann sphere to itself, which may explain why they work naturally with the one-point compactification.

Comment: "should we abandon"? Could, yes. "Should"? when? In books about rational functions? You could. While making research or thinking about them, makes no difference. People think however it is more comfortable for them. In class? No, NO NO!!! Rational functions are not all there are and the two directions you can go away from $0$ on the reals are useful to study some functions. This reminds me of that thing they do in that terrible book Steward's Calculus, in which they neglect slant asymptotes, and only see them for rational functions, and then they only have one and compute it by long division.

Comment: So, what is happening in Steward's Calculus is that students don't get to learn how to compute slant asymptotes, i.e. they don't really know what a slant asymptote is. I would say. Sacrifice in the breadth of the examples, the types of functions seen, is ok. Sacrifice the breadth of the technique. No. So, that is why the question: Where should we abandon the $\pm\infty$?

Comment: It's pretty nice to have the two-point compactification in integration, or when dealing with semicontinuous functions.